# My file gets truncated in Hive after uploading it completely to Cloudera Hue

Tags: hive, cloudera, hue, data-import

I am using Cloudera's Hue. In the file browser, I upload a .csv file with about 3,000 rows (my file is small <400k).

After uploading the file I go to the Data Browser, create a table and import the data into it.

When I go to Hive and perform a simple query (say SELECT * FROM table) I only see results for 99 rows. The original .csv has more than those rows.

When I do other queries I notice that several rows of data are missing although they show in the preview in the Hue File Browser.

I have tried with other files and they also get truncated sometimes at 65 rows or 165 rows.

I have also removed all the "," from the .csv data before uploading the file.

Comment: Is it a Hue version < 3.7? It sounds like an old bug

Comment: The Hue version is 3.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this. There were several issues that appeared to cause a truncation.

The main was that the variable type automatically set after importing the data was assigned according to the first lines. So when the data type changed from TinyINT to INT it got truncated or changed to "NULL". To solve this perform EDA and change the datatype before creating the table.

Other issues were that the memory I had assigned to the virtual machine slowed the preview process and that the csv contained commas. You can set the VM to have more memory or change a csv to tab separated.

Comment: And FYI the tiny detection has been change to something bigger to avoid this problem: https://github.com/cloudera/hue/commit/f25fbd9

Comment: Thank you Romain for your comments and follow up.